# ASP.NET Core not post data to Action Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When posting data to Action Method from Ajax Post to Action Method, model is always null. Tried with FromBody and without it, both fails. I am using .NET Core 7.0

My Controller Action Method

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> AddOrUpdateAddress([FromBody]AddressViewModel model)
{
    var address = _mapper.Map<Address>(model);
```

My Ajax function

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "/Company/AddOrUpdateAddress",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json;",
    data: JSON.stringify(address),
    success: function (response) {
        company.details.address.addEdit.closeDetails();
            $.notify('Saved', { position: "top right", className: "success" });
    },
    error: function (e) {
        $.notify('Error', { position: "top right", className: "error" });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Model is as below

```
public class AddressViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Address Type")]
        public int? AddressTypeId { get; set; }
        public AddressType? Type { get; set; }
        public string? Address1 { get; set; }
        public string? Address2 { get; set; }
        public string? City { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = RegistrationTooltip.State)]
        public int? StateId { get; set; }
        public string? StateName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = RegistrationTooltip.Country)]
        //[DefaultValue(0)]        
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Zip")]
        public string? Zip { get; set; }
        public string? FullAddress =>
            new Regex("[ ]{2,}", RegexOptions.None).Replace(
                $"{Address1?.Humanize(LetterCasing.Title)}, {Address2?.Humanize(LetterCasing.Title)}<br/> {City?.Humanize(LetterCasing.Title)} {(!StateId.HasValue ? StateName?.Humanize(LetterCasing.Title) : State?.Name?.Humanize(LetterCasing.Title))} - {Zip}<br/> <span><img src=\"/3rdParty/flags/blank.gif\" class=\"flag flag-{Country?.TwoLetterIsoCode}\" alt=\"{Country?.Name?.Humanize(LetterCasing.Title)}\"> {Country?.Name?.Humanize(LetterCasing.Title)}</span>",
                " ");
        public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Is Default")]
        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Primary Hr Contact")]
        public string? PrimaryHrContactUserId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Primary Finance Contact")]
        public string? PrimaryFinanceContactUserId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Primary Facility Contact")]
        public string? PrimaryFacilityContactUserId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Additional Hr Recipients")]
        public string? AdditionalHrRecipients { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Additional Finance Recipients")]
        public string? AdditionalFinanceRecipients { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Additional Facility Recipients")]
        public string? AdditionalFacilityRecipients { get; set; }
        public  State? State { get; set; }
        public Country? Country { get; set; }

        public List<ShiftViewModel>? Shifts { get; set; }

        public List<OperatingHourViewModel>? OperatingHours { get; set; }
        
        public UserLiteDTO ? PrimaryHrContactUser { get; set; }
       
        public UserLiteDTO? PrimaryFinanceContactUser { get; set; }
     
        public UserLiteDTO? PrimaryFacilityContactUser { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }
```

stringify body messages

```
{
    "CountryId": "2",
    "AddressTypeId": "9",
    "Address1": "7th Floor, South Wing, ",
    "Address2": "Krishe Sapphire",
    "Zip": "500081",
    "StateId": "92",
    "City": "Hyderabad",
    "StateName": "",
    "Id": "607",
    "PrimaryHrContactUserId": "",
    "PrimaryFinanceContactUserId": "",
    "PrimaryFacilityContactUserId": "",
    "IsDefault": false,
    "IsDeleted": false,
    "OperatingHours": [
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "Day": "Sunday",
            "OpeningTime": "",
            "ClosingTime": "",
            "IsClosed": true,
            "CompanyId":1,
            "AddressId":1
        },
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "Day": "Monday",
            "OpeningTime": "11:00 AM",
            "ClosingTime": "4:30 PM",
            "IsClosed": false,
            "CompanyId":1,
            "AddressId":1
        },
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "Day": "Tuesday",
            "OpeningTime": "",
            "ClosingTime": "",
            "IsClosed": false,
            "CompanyId":1,
            "AddressId":1
        },
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "Day": "Wednesday",
            "OpeningTime": "",
            "ClosingTime": "",
            "IsClosed": false,
            "CompanyId":1,
            "AddressId":1
        },
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "Day": "Thursday",
            "OpeningTime": "",
            "ClosingTime": "",
            "IsClosed": false,
            "CompanyId":1,
            "AddressId":1
        },
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "Day": "Friday",
            "OpeningTime": "",
            "ClosingTime": "",
            "IsClosed": false,
            "CompanyId":1,
            "AddressId":1
        },
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "Day": "Saturday",
            "OpeningTime": "",
            "ClosingTime": "",
            "IsClosed": false,
            "CompanyId":1,
            "AddressId":1
        }
    ],
    "Shifts": [
        {
            "Id": "0",
            "ShiftName": "Regular",
            "OpeningTime": "",
            "ClosingTime": "",
            "IsActive": false,
            "CompanyId": 1,
            "AddressId":1
        },
        {
            "Id": "0",
            "ShiftName": "Morning",
            "OpeningTime": "",
            "ClosingTime": "",
            "IsActive": false,
            "CompanyId": 1,
            "AddressId":1
        },
        {
            "Id": "0",
            "ShiftName": "Night",
            "OpeningTime": "",
            "ClosingTime": "",
            "IsActive": false,
            "CompanyId": 1,
            "AddressId":1
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the sample code base to reproduce the error
https://filetransfer.io/data-package/16ZC8Bck#link

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Run the above code in VisualStudio
2. Using PostMan or some other Restful API tool do a HTTPS Post with the payload (request body) shared above as stringify body messages

Comment: What is `AddressViewModel`? What is the result of `JSON.stringify(address)`?

Comment: Added them both to the question

Comment: If you check `model == null` what is the result? `true`?

Comment: model is coming as null

Comment: TBH was not able to repro. Can you please post a [mre]?

Comment: Added codebase in the the question with reproducing steps

Comment: post to this url https://localhost:port/Company/AddOrUpdateAddress

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254351/discussion-between-habo-and-guru-stron).

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks okay, but you have some data inconsistency in your model and payload.

For example, I found that you expect `Id` fields as `integer`, but pass them as `string`. You  also have numerous nested models. But the main problem is that in some of your nested moodel you expected `TimeSpan` but passed incorred data or empty string.

In my example i used TimeSpan values equal `00:00:00.0000001`

Once I fixed that locally, the model can be parsed sucessfully
[image]

Comment: Yea. I just narrowed it down to TimeSpan property. I changed it to String property and casted it on the model inside, that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

as @adalyat Nazirov pointed, the issue was with timespan property. I changed the property to string and handled in codebase then post worked.

```
private string? _openingTimeString;
        private string _closingTimeString;

 public string? OpeningTimeString
        {
            get { return _openingTimeString; }
            set
            {
                _openingTimeString = value;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) && DateTime.TryParse(value, out var _openingTime))
                {
                    OpeningTime = _openingTime.TimeOfDay;
                }
            }
        }
        public string? ClosingTimeString
        {
            get { return _closingTimeString; }
            set
            {
                _closingTimeString = value;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) && DateTime.TryParse(value, out var _closingTime))
                {
                    ClosingTime = _closingTime.TimeOfDay;
                }
            }
        }
        [Display(Name = "Opening Time"), JsonIgnore]
        public TimeSpan? OpeningTime { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Closing Time"), JsonIgnore]
        public TimeSpan? ClosingTime { get; set; }
```